# Discrete Math Combinatorics Homework Help

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

1. Find the value of
   ${n\choose0} + 3{n\choose1} + 9{n\choose2} + {27}{n\choose3} + \dots + 3^n{n\choose n}$

I know that ${n\choose0} = 1$,  ${n\choose1} = n$ so $3{n\choose1} = 3n$, and ${n\choose n}=1$ so $3^n{n\choose n}=3^n$. But I don't realize the pattern going on here.

2.Color all the odd numbers in Pascals triangle red and all the even numbers blue. What pattern do you get? Describe it as precisely as you can.

For this one I realize you get this picture going on:

[image: pascal's triangle- even & odd number pattern]

So you get like upside down decreasing in size triangles for the even numbers inside of the bigger triangles marked by the odd numbers. But I'm not sure exactly what I should be saying about the picture. Am I missing a crucial discovery here?

3.Let $k,l,m,n \in Z \geq 0$ be such that $n=k+l+m$. The trinomial coefficient ${n \choose k,l,m}$ is given by the rules:

1. for $k+l=n$, ${n\choose k,l,0} = {n \choose k,0,l} = {n \choose 0,k,l} = {n\choose k}$
2. ${n\choose k,l,m} = {n-1 \choose k-1,l,m} + {n-1 \choose k,l-1,m} + {n\choose k,l,m-1}$

The following questions use this definition.

(a) What are all the trinomial coefficients for $n=1,2,3$?

(b) Describe the "triangle" of trinomial coefficients (Hint: Think three dimensional Pascal's triangle).

This one I just don't really understand because of "trinomial" talk. I can visualize a Pascal's "pyramid." One where the number below is a sum of the 3 above it. Something like that. But other than that, I'm not really sure what's going on.

Comment: To be clear, there are 3 different questions posted. They all involve combinatorics and counting.

Comment: Please ask one question per post, take answers and think / work on them for a while, then ask more if needed.

Comment: For the second question you might read about [self-similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-similarity) and, more specifically, the [Sierpiński triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle).

Comment: Your pyramid is what they’re looking for in 3(b), and 3(a) is just a matter of following the rules to compute all possible values of $\binom{n}{k,\ell,m}$ for $n=1,2,3$. From the pyramid you can see that there is just one value for $n=0$, then $3$ for $n=1$, $6$ for $n=2$, and ... how many for $n=3$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first, recognize the binomial theorem:

\begin{align*}
&{n \choose 0} + 3 {n \choose 1} + 9 {n \choose 2} + ... + 3^n {n \choose n} \\&= {n \choose 0} 1^n 3^0 + {n \choose 1} 1^{n - 1} 3^1 + {n \choose 2} 1^{n - 2} 3^2 + ... + {n \choose n} 1^0 3^n \\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k} 1^{n - k} 3^k \\
&= (3 + 1)^n
\end{align*}